# UseHostCompilerIfAvailable False causes an "One or more types required to compile a dynamic expression cannot be found" error

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, msbuild, msbuildcommunitytasks

The C# `dynamic` type seems not to compile when `UseHostCompilerIfAvailable` is set to `false`. I have both the required references `Microsoft.CSharp` and `System.Core` in my project, but it refuses to recognize it. Using the integrated Visual Studio compiler works, however.

The offending line is:

```
dynamic obj = this.Engine.Operations.CreateInstance(pytype);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind, it seemed that including the `Microsoft.Scripting.Core` assembly was the cause of this.

Comment: You should mark this as answered so that people know the question inst outstanding.

Comment: I couldn't before - had to wait two days.